# How to find the latest week and month from MySQL

Tags: mysql

[This DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16955/2) shows by month. And [this DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16955/1) shows by week. However I want to display

Q1: only this week of each student.

Q2: only this month of each student.

Q3: only last week of each student.

Q4: only last month of each student.

How can I achieve this?

```
CREATE TABLE `hw_homework` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `studentid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `subjectid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `teacherid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `hw_homework` (`id`, `studentid`, `subjectid`, `assignment_name`, `teacherid`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 29, 5, '5E', 20, '2012-10-31 13:58:40'),
(2, 15, 5, '32B', 20, '2012-10-31 13:59:54'),
(3, 29, 4, 'Q2A', 20, '2012-10-30 17:53:46'),
(4, 29, 11, '6E', 20, '2012-10-02 20:06:39'),
(5, 29, 11, 'C15', 20, '2012-10-16 20:06:30'),
(6, 15, 11, '7A', 20, '2012-09-19 20:08:05'),
(7, 29, 5, '3B', 20, '2012-09-14 20:08:12'),
(8, 29, 13, '6E', 32, '2012-10-29 20:23:46'),
(9, 29, 11, '7E', 18, '2012-10-30 14:35:14'),
(10, 2, 5, '5E', 20, '2012-10-21 13:58:40'),
(11, 2, 5, '5E', 20, '2012-10-30 13:58:40'),
(12, 2, 5, '5E', 20, '2012-10-31 13:58:40');
```

By month

```
SELECT  studentID, 
        DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M') `month`,
        COUNT(studentID) totalMissed
FROM hw_homework
-- WHERE studentID = ''
GROUP BY studentID, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M')
```

By week

```
SELECT  studentID, 
        DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%U') `WeekNo`,
        COUNT(studentID) totalMissed
FROM hw_homework
-- WHERE studentID = ''
GROUP BY studentID, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%U')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1** :

```
SELECT  studentID, 
        DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%U') `WeekNo`,
        COUNT(studentID) totalMissed
FROM hw_homework
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%U') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%U')
-- AND studentID = ''
GROUP BY studentID, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%U')
```

**A2** :

```
SELECT  studentID, 
        DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M') `WeekNo`,
        COUNT(studentID) totalMissed
FROM hw_homework
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%M')
-- AND studentID = ''
GROUP BY studentID, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M')
```

**A3** :

```
SELECT  studentID, 
        DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%U') `WeekNo`,
        COUNT(studentID) totalMissed
FROM hw_homework he
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%U') = (SELECT MAX(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%U')) FROM hw_homework hi WHERE hi.studentID = he.studentID)
-- AND studentID = ''
GROUP BY studentID, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%U')
```

**A4** :

```
SELECT  studentID, 
        DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M') `WeekNo`,
        COUNT(studentID) totalMissed
FROM hw_homework he
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M') = (SELECT MAX(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%M')) FROM hw_homework hi WHERE hi.studentID = he.studentID)
-- AND studentID = ''
GROUP BY studentID, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M')
```